# Documentum Docbase is unable to save an object

Tags: repository, documentum

When I using the following API script to save an object,it just hangs up and no result...

```
link,c,object_id,/temp1/temp2 save,c,object_id
```

Also I have other test like ：

1. create a new dm_folder object and link to /temp1/temp2, object created.
2. update dm_folder object to link and unlink, object is linked and unlinked to expected folder paths.

All the above two steps works, but not the ‘save’, why?

Could you guys give me some advice on this issue?

Answer (score 0):

You are mistaking somewhere. API command

```
link,c,<object_d>,<path_to_link_object_to>
save,c,<object_id>
```

works as expected, i.e. it links object to specified path which is provided as last argument in first command. 
Try formatting better your question so we can identify your syntax errors if there are any.